# Copying Files from Linux Servers

Tags: c++, gcc, terminal, putty, file-copying

Is there any way to save a file from the linux servers to my desktop. In my college we are using windows XP and use Putty to connect to the college Linux server. We have individual accounts on the server. I have created a lot of cpp files on it and now want to copy them to my pendrive so I can work with them on my home PC. Also please mention a way to copy from desktop to the server(i.e., home of my account in it).

Thank you for your help in advance. :) :D

Answer (score 3):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) does this very nicely in either SFTP, SCP, FTPS or FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your permissions and what is on the box you can email the contents of files to yourself.

```
mail -s "Subject" myemail@somewhere.com < /home/me/file.txt
```

Can alwasy test with something simple

```
mail -s “Hi” myemail@somewhere.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up an online account for a version control system (GIT, Mercurial, Bazaar, SVN), and store your files there. That way, you can just "clone", "pull" or "update" the files wherever you are that has a reasonable connection to the internet.

There are quite a few sites that have free online version control systems, so it's mostly a case of "pick a version control system", and type  "free online `vcs` server" into your favourite search engine (replace `vcs` with your choice of version control system).

An added benefit is that you will have version control and thus be able to go back and forth between different version (very useful when you realise that all the changes you've done this morning ended up being a bad route to follow [I do that sometimes, still, after over 30 years of programming - I just tend to know sooner when I've messed up and go back to the original code], so you want to go back to where you were last afternoon, before you started breaking it).